# How to split a string at every point, question mark and exclamation mark in r

Tags: r, string

As the title says, I should split a string at every . ! and ?
That doesn't work:

```
strsplit(x, "/ (\\?|\\.|!) /")
```

```
$`352`
[1] "Saudi Arabian Oil Minister Hisham (...) 
the\n... accord and it will never sell its oil at prices below the\npronounced prices under any circumstance.\"\n    Saudi Arabia was a main architect of December pact under\nwhich OPEC agreed to cut its total oil output ceiling by 7.25\npct and return to fixed prices of around 18 dollars a barrel.\n Reuter"

$`353`
[1] "Kuwait's oil minister said (...) 
 daily (bpd).\n    Crude oil prices fell sharply last week as international\noil traders and analysts estimated the 13-nation OPEC was\npumping up to one million bpd over its self-imposed limits.\n Reuter"

$`368`
[1] "The port of Philadelphia (...) 
the ship on the high tide.\n    After delivering oil to a refinery in Paulsboro, New\nJersey, the ship apparently lost its steering and hit the power\ntransmission line carrying power from the nuclear plant to the\nstate of Delaware.\n Reuter"
```

I shortened it with "(...)" here, so that's not part of the code obviously.
There should be far more splits because there are points where it doesn't split.

Comment: Have you tried without the dashes (`/`) and parenthesis (`()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan V. Solórzano is right:

```r
x <- "Ceci.est!un?pipe. . ."
strsplit(x, "\\?|\\.|!")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "Ceci" "est"  "un"   "pipe" " "    " "
```